# Crystal Report formula field formula that pulls a date out of a string?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I need to extract a date out of a invoice number and subtract one month from the month. 
For example if a invoice number is I2011101002683 I need to pull out the 2011, four numbers starting a position 1, and then the 10, two numbers starting a position 5.
and display the date in a 2011/09 format. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
numbervar year_start := 2;
numbervar year_len := 4;
numbervar month_start := year_start + year_len;
numbervar month_len:= 2;

mid({Command.InvoiceNumber},year_start,year_len) + "/" + 
mid({Command.InvoiceNumber},month_start,month_len);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a formula field to extract the date:

```
//{@invoice_date}
//I|2011|10|1002683 --> Date(2011, 10, 1)
Date(ToNumber({Command.InvoiceNumber}[2 To 5]), ToNumber({Command.InvoiceNumber}[6 to 7]), 1)
```

Add the resulting formula to the canvas; format it as desired.